# Find the next prime at/after a given integer

Tags: performance, c

I created a function that returns the next prime number greater or equal to the number given as an argument. My code works well, but I find it is very slow.

The test suite take almost 60s and I want less than 10s.  Can the code be optimised to achieve this?

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
     int    i;

    i = (int)nb - 1;
    if (nb <= 1)
        return (0);
    while (i > 1)
    {
        if (nb % i == 0)
            return (0);
        i--;
    }
    return (1);
}

int ft_find_next_prime(int nb)
{

    while (ft_is_prime(nb) == 0)
    {
        ft_is_prime(nb);
        nb++;
    }
    return (nb);
}
```

## Tests

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d -> %d\n", -1868, ft_find_next_prime(-1868));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 0, ft_find_next_prime(0));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 1, ft_find_next_prime(1));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2, ft_find_next_prime(2));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 7853, ft_find_next_prime(7853));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 78989, ft_find_next_prime(78989));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483643, ft_find_next_prime(2147483643));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483645, ft_find_next_prime(2147483645));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483646, ft_find_next_prime(2147483646));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483647, ft_find_next_prime(2147483647));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 203785, ft_find_next_prime(203785));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 14357, ft_find_next_prime(14357));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 389654, ft_find_next_prime(389654));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 356376, ft_find_next_prime(356376));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 111641, ft_find_next_prime(111641));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 139803, ft_find_next_prime(139803));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 98368, ft_find_next_prime(98368));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 172597, ft_find_next_prime(172597));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 178697, ft_find_next_prime(178697));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 295994, ft_find_next_prime(295994));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 66107, ft_find_next_prime(66107));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 348224, ft_find_next_prime(348224));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 424018, ft_find_next_prime(424018));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 182868, ft_find_next_prime(182868));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 279638, ft_find_next_prime(279638));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 215132, ft_find_next_prime(215132));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 130734, ft_find_next_prime(130734));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 254567, ft_find_next_prime(254567));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 287850, ft_find_next_prime(287850));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 101486, ft_find_next_prime(101486));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 338034, ft_find_next_prime(338034));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 367221, ft_find_next_prime(367221));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 352888, ft_find_next_prime(352888));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 296057, ft_find_next_prime(296057));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 420476, ft_find_next_prime(420476));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 337541, ft_find_next_prime(337541));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 269965, ft_find_next_prime(269965));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 262287, ft_find_next_prime(262287));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 298128, ft_find_next_prime(298128));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 81045, ft_find_next_prime(81045));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 6816, ft_find_next_prime(6816));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 200353, ft_find_next_prime(200353));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 87717, ft_find_next_prime(87717));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 275623, ft_find_next_prime(275623));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 20140, ft_find_next_prime(20140));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 145069, ft_find_next_prime(145069));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 309422, ft_find_next_prime(309422));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 288966, ft_find_next_prime(288966));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 196808, ft_find_next_prime(196808));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 408696, ft_find_next_prime(408696));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 308434, ft_find_next_prime(308434));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 234200, ft_find_next_prime(234200));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 12514, ft_find_next_prime(12514));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 363758, ft_find_next_prime(363758));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 257776, ft_find_next_prime(257776));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 312563, ft_find_next_prime(312563));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 757, ft_find_next_prime(757));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 398583, ft_find_next_prime(398583));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 36608, ft_find_next_prime(36608));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 35590, ft_find_next_prime(35590));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 174862, ft_find_next_prime(174862));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 409874, ft_find_next_prime(409874));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 68893, ft_find_next_prime(68893));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 87838, ft_find_next_prime(87838));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 284334, ft_find_next_prime(284334));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 48416, ft_find_next_prime(48416));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 32034, ft_find_next_prime(32034));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 125232, ft_find_next_prime(125232));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 418100, ft_find_next_prime(418100));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 312630, ft_find_next_prime(312630));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 288568, ft_find_next_prime(288568));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 398662, ft_find_next_prime(398662));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 46407, ft_find_next_prime(46407));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 121678, ft_find_next_prime(121678));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 406867, ft_find_next_prime(406867));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 61269, ft_find_next_prime(61269));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 315739, ft_find_next_prime(315739));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 271203, ft_find_next_prime(271203));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 192870, ft_find_next_prime(192870));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 114535, ft_find_next_prime(114535));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 173417, ft_find_next_prime(173417));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 248682, ft_find_next_prime(248682));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 306029, ft_find_next_prime(306029));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 108921, ft_find_next_prime(108921));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 210815, ft_find_next_prime(210815));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 252289, ft_find_next_prime(252289));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 72584, ft_find_next_prime(72584));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 297710, ft_find_next_prime(297710));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 27544, ft_find_next_prime(27544));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 373150, ft_find_next_prime(373150));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 219888, ft_find_next_prime(219888));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 156579, ft_find_next_prime(156579));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 271274, ft_find_next_prime(271274));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 295751, ft_find_next_prime(295751));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 207022, ft_find_next_prime(207022));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 143794, ft_find_next_prime(143794));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 390643, ft_find_next_prime(390643));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 186808, ft_find_next_prime(186808));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 230330, ft_find_next_prime(230330));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 175035, ft_find_next_prime(175035));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 101832, ft_find_next_prime(101832));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 205261, ft_find_next_prime(205261));
    printf("%d -> %d\n",389070, ft_find_next_prime(389070));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 397788, ft_find_next_prime(397788));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 6117, ft_find_next_prime(6117));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 169448, ft_find_next_prime(169448));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 393706, ft_find_next_prime(393706));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 286195, ft_find_next_prime(286195));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 334329, ft_find_next_prime(334329));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 184829, ft_find_next_prime(184829));
}
```

Comment: I'm not well known in the C language, but that `main` method looks like it should be made into real automated tests, instead of a long `main`.

Comment: In the future it would be better to add a follow up question with a link back to the original question rather than editing the question. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yeah, you are right I got this from a trackback of the system that evaluated me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do much better with ft_find_next_prime().

First, there is no prime < 2, so if you start there, the prime is 2.

Second, all primes >2 are odd, so you don't need to consider even numbers.

A general point, not related to your algorithm, is that it is often unwise to test for equality to your boolean values.  Just use the value directly in the conditional test.

Combined with @Top-Master's point, yields:

```
int ft_find_next_prime(int nb)
{
    if (nb <= 2) return 2; /*early numbers*/
    nb |= 1; /*Ensure it is odd*/
    while (!ft_is_prime(nb))
    {
        nb += 2;
    }
    return nb;
}
```

The issue not explicitly raised about `ft_is_prime()`: You should check from the most probable to the least.  I.e. start with 2, not nb-1 (or even `sqrt(nb)`).  While it is O(n) or O(sqrt(n)) for a prime either way, you will get faster results for composites.

One other odd twist you can do:  My implementation of `ft_find_next_prime` never passes an even number to `ft_is_prime`.  Thus, you could make a `ft_is_prime_given_odd` function and skip the first tests in @Gh0st's second optimized version.

Answer (score 3):

Function `ft_is_prime` has complexity `O(n)` which is very slow as your input can be large. Simple optimization is to check divisors up to the square root of the number you are testing. There are [other algorithms to check primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), but I think it is good enough in this case. I would also make nb `long long`. It can be implemented this way:

```cpp
int ft_is_prime(long long nb) {
    if (nb <= 1)
        return 0;
    for(long long i = 2; i*i <= nb; i++){
        if(nb % i == 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can also check at first if 2 divides `nb` and then it would look like this (it doesn't change complexity):

```cpp
if(nb % 2 == 0)
    return 0;
for(long long i = 3; i*i <= nb; i+=2){
    if(nb % i == 0){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `i*i <= nb` overflows when `nb` is a large prime.  Consider `i <= nb/i` 2) Error: `if(nb % 2 == 0) return 0;` should be `if(nb % 2 == 0) return nb == 2;`.

Comment: @Gh0st Thank you neverthelessI don't have permission to use a library or a for loop, no externe function **Allowed functions: None** , and `long long` augmented the run time * 4.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int ft_is_prime(int nb)
> ```

This is a boolean function, so we should document that:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ft_is_prime(int nb)
```

> ```
>  int    i;
>
> i = (int)nb - 1;
> ```

We can combine the declaration and assignment, and we don't need to cast (as `nb` is already of type `int`):

```
int i = nb - 1;
```

> ```
>     return (0);
> ```

There's no need for parentheses there - plain old `return 0;` is simpler and more readable.

> ```
> while (i > 1)
> ```

Testing primality by trial division is already slow, but we've made it even slower by testing the largest candidate factors first.  We'll eliminate numbers much more quickly if we start with the smallest candidates.  And we can stop when we reach the square root of `nb`:

```
#include <math.h>

bool ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 2)
        return false;

    /* add one to ensure round-up */
    const int limit = (int)sqrt(nb) + 1;
    for (int i = 2;  i <= limit;  ++i) {
        if (nb % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* no factors found => must be prime */
    return true;
}
```

We can go much faster by not considering any even numbers other than 2:

```
    if (nb % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    /* add one to ensure round-up */
    const int limit = (int)sqrt(nb) + 1;
    for (int i = 3;  i <= limit;  i += 2) {
        if (nb % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

That code using `sqrt()` is a little problematic, because it uses floating-point arithmetic, which is inexact (necessitating that `+1`) and, on many platforms, much slower than integer arithmetic.  However, we can simply use `i <= nb / i`, which shouldn't cause extra division: a good optimising compiler will use a single operation to compute both this `nb / i` and the `nb % i` on the next line.

---

## Improved code

These changes improve the run time of the test suite from well over 1 minute to under 0.01 seconds (both compiled with `gcc -O3`).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

bool ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 2 || nb % 2 == 0 && nb != 2) {
        return false;
    }

   for (int i = 3;  i <= nb/i;  i += 2) {
        if (nb % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* no factors found => must be prime */
    return true;
}

int ft_find_next_prime(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 2) {
        return 2;
    }

    while (!ft_is_prime(nb)) {
        ++nb;
    }
    return nb;
}
```

---

To improve further, we should ditch the trial division and move to a better algorithm, perhaps using a prime number wheel.

Comment: New term for me: [prime number wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).  LSNED.

Comment: A good compiler with `for (int i = 3;  i <= nb/i;  i += 2) { if (nb % i == 0) { return false; }  }` will see the nearby `nb/i` and `nb%i` and calculate both for the price of one.  Or use `div()`.  `sqrt(nb)` is a problem when `(double) nb` inexact (`int` as 64-bit, `nb` as `long long` ...) or expensive on processors lacking a FP unit.  IAC, OP's slowness is solved by code like yours with O(sqrt(n)) time.

Comment: Of course - I had completely overlooked the `%` in the same loop.  That form is much better, and I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You was calling `ft_is_prime` function two times, try:

```
int ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
    int i;

    // Validate arguments.
    if (nb <= 1)
        return 0;

    for (i = nb - 1; i > 1; --i) {
        if (nb % i == 0)
            return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}

int ft_find_next_prime(int nb)
{

    while ( ! ft_is_prime(nb)) {
        ++nb;
    }
    return nb;
}
```

But I am sure you seek more though.